# How to get the changed item in table to sync with database?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, x-editable

I am using xeditable.js to change the current content of a cell in a table and my intention is to take the change and send it with a http request(put) to the backend, which updates the database.

Here is the table with can be modified:

```
<tbody class="connectedSortable" style="display: block; height: 262px; overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
            <tr ng-repeat="station in stations | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchStation" style="width: 100%">
              <td> <a href="#" editable-text="station.id">{{ station.id }}</a> </td>
              <td> <a href="#" editable-text="station.name">{{ station.name }}</a> </td>
              <td> <a href="#" editable-text="station.lon">{{ station.lon }}</a> </td>
              <td> <a href="#" editable-text="station.lat">{{ station.lat }}</a> </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

My problem is that I have no idea, where I get the whole row(the backend needs it), in which something was changed, because xeditable does the job for me.

If you need more information, please do not hesitate to ask, I have more code here ;)

PS: Maybe this is helpful for you.

```
var app = angular.module("liveSearchApp", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
      editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/). They are using forms to update each row here. Here **onbeforesave** directive is pointing to function that will upload row to database with **user** being whole row.

```
onbeforesave="saveUser($data, user.id)"
```

Comment: This looks nice, but I'm not able to use it in my case, maybe I don't understand the clue here. 
The backend requires a JSONObject with id, name, lon, lat(which are the contents of the table cells in the row, where the edit button was clicked), but how do I need $data in this way or how can i convert it correctly?

Comment: In this case data is an object which contains row cells. You can use JSON.stringify(data) or angular.toJson(data) to create JSON string. But  you won't need it because method sending data to backend $http.post(url, data) convert data object to JSON automatically before submitting it.  Ask if you need more info.